# How can I add a comment to either a selection or the entire line with one keybinding like the sublime keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I comment selected text, only that text is commented in Sublime Text but in VSCode the entire line is commented not just the selected text.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can comment out part of a line by selecting the text and clicking `ALT+SHIFT+A` - Toggle Block comment option.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/q7K7udz.gif]

Comment: Thanks man, it's solve my problem =]
one curiosity, can I put this shortcut together of the `Ctrl + ;` equal in Sublime Text? In Sublime Text it's recognizes if the selection is all line or isolate/block

Comment: @RafaeldeSouza Yes you can, go to keyboard shortcuts and search for `toggle block comment` and assign whatever key you want. example https://i.imgur.com/gwiPg9p.png

Answer (score 0):

With a macro extension [macro-commander](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeff-hykin.macro-commander) you can do what I think you want - toggle block comment if you select something less than the entire line, otherwise if you select nothing on the line or the entire line toggle line comment it.

[image]

With this in your settings.json:

```
"macros": {

  "commentSelection" : [
  
    { 
      "javascript": [

        "const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;",
        "const document = editor.document;",
        "const selection = editor.selection;",

        // Get the trimmed "word(s)" of the selection
        "const word = document.getText(selection).trim();",

        // Get the full line of text on the line of the selection
        "let lineNumber = selection.start.line;",
        "const line = document.lineAt(lineNumber).text.trim();",

        // `!word` means the cursor is on the line but nothing selected
        "let selectionEqualsEntireLine = !word || (line === word);",

        "if (selectionEqualsEntireLine) vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.commentLine');",
        "else vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.blockComment');",
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and your keybinding to trigger it:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+;",                       // use whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "macros.commentSelection"
}
```

---

---

Alternatively, and much simpler, try these keybindings and no macro at all:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+;",
    "command": "editor.action.blockComment",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
  },

  {
    "key": "ctrl+;",
    "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
  },
```

The only difference from the macro is if you select all the text - with the macro you would get a line comment, with these keybindings you will get a block comment.  I an not sure which version you prefer.